# How to move a docker-compose environment to other computer

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am developing a service using docker-compose and I deploy the the containers to a remote host using this commands:

```
eval $(docker-machine env digitaloceanserver)
docker-compose build && docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up -d
```

My problem is that I'm changing laptop and I exported the docker-machines to the new laptop and I can activate them.
But when I try to deploy new changes it raises these errors:

> Creating postgres ... error Creating redis    ...ERROR: for postgres 
>   Cannot create container for service postgres: b'Conflict. The
>   container name "/postgres" is already in use by container
>   "612f3887544224aeCreating redis    ... errorERROR: for redis  Cannot
>   create container for service redis: b'Conflict. The container name
>   "/redis" is already in use by container
>   "01875947f0ce7ba3978238525923e54e0c800fa0a4b419dd2a28cc07c285eb78".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.'ERROR: for postgres  Cannot create container for service
>   postgres: b'Conflict. The container name "/postgres" is already in use
>   by container
>   "612f3887544224ae79f67e29552b4d97e246104b8a057b3a03d39f6546dbbd38".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.'ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis:
>   b'Conflict. The container name "/redis" is already in use by container
>   "01875947f0ce7ba3978238525923e54e0c800fa0a4b419dd2a28cc07c285eb78".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.' ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

My docker-compose.yml is this:

```
services:
  nginx:
    build: './docks/nginx/.'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - letsencrypt_certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - letsencrypt_www:/var/www/letsencrypt
    volumes_from:
      - web:ro
    depends_on:
      - web

  letsencrypt:
    build: './docks/certbot/.'
    command: /bin/true
    volumes:
      - letsencrypt_certs:/etc/letsencrypt
      - letsencrypt_www:/var/www/letsencrypt

  web:
    build: './sources/.'
    image: 'websource'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:8000:8000'
    env_file: '.env'
    command: 'gunicorn cuidum.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --reload --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance --log-level=debug --access-logfile=- --log-file=-'
    volumes:
      - 'cachedata:/cache'
      - 'mediadata:/media'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  celery_worker:
    image: 'websource'
    env_file: '.env'
    command: 'python -m celery -A cuidum worker -l debug'
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  celery_beat:
    container_name: 'celery_beat'
    image: 'websource'
    env_file: '.env'
    command: 'python -m celery -A cuidum beat --pidfile= -l debug'
    volumes_from:
      - web
    depends_on:
      - web

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: 'mdillon/postgis'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/'

  redis:
    container_name: 'redis'
    image: 'redis:3.2.0'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redisdata:/data'

volumes:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
  cachedata:
  mediadata:
  staticdata:
  letsencrypt_certs:
  letsencrypt_www:
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re seeing those errors because you’re explicitly setting `container_name:`, and those same container names are used elsewhere.  Remove those explicit settings.  (You don’t need them even for inter-container DNS; Docker Compose automatically creates an alias for you using the name of the service block.)

There are still potential issues from port conflicts.  If your other PostgreSQL container is listening on the same (default) host port 5432 then the one you declare in this `docker-compose.yml` file will conflict with it.  You might be able to just not expose your database container ports, or you might need to change the port numbers in this file.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to deploy a new container. I want to build a new version of the container and replace it but preserving the postgres data.